# Why does Chrome Dev Tools not show "computed" tab?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I'm learning about Box Model in Dev Tools, but **I'm unable to see the "computed tab" when navigating through developer tools**. I re-downloaded Chrome and Canary 2 but neither of them made a difference in showing the computed tab between "styles" and "event listeners". Has anyone come across this issue in the past?

*I've attached a screenshot of what I'm seeing. 
[image of dev tools not listing computed tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x73d6.png)

Comment: The panel on the right is the Computed panel. It's shown this way because of small screen estate.

Comment: Thank you wOxxOm! If you submit this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

Since Chrome 85, the `Computed` section is always displayed as a tab.

[What's New In DevTools (Chrome 85)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/06/devtools#computed-pane)

**Update:** As [@machineghost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5921/machineghost) noted below, you can now toggle the *Show Computed Styles sidebar* in the `Styles` tab (top-right corner) to have both features visible at the same time.

Comment: Wait what, so I can't see 'styles' and 'computed' at the same time? I liked it like that, was useful! Now I'm swapping tabs all the time and my fingers and my sanity are all slowly wearing down to stumps. Is there another way to get that view??

Comment: I want that feature back, it´s so sad

Comment: It's still there: see 00-BBB's answer.   While Petr Nagy is correct in saying "the `Computed` section is always displayed as a tab.", it's *also* available on the Styles tab ... if you click the button to show it there.

Answer (score 3):

To always display the tab:

1) [Go into Dev tool settings by ellipses at the top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AKQn.png)

2) [Change Panel layout to Vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrMav.png)

If you leave "Panel Layout" at the defaul "auto" setting, you can only see the computed tab when the dev tool window is greater than a certain width.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone confused like me, this took me months to find..! *(unless it was just added in an update)*

Click and it shows the computed tab like it always used to

[image: chrome show computed tab button]

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit confusing as it gets moved around based on the size of styles panel. No idea why.

If it is not wide enough it shows up below the 'layout'

[image]

It appears as a tab if the panel is wide enough

[image]

Comment: While changing layout is a workaround, this should likely be the accepted answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me . Now i can open style/element/computed at the same time.

1. Open setting ( click on gear Icon )
2. Set Panel Layout option to Horizontal
3. Close the settings now & you are good to go :)